# Slow eager loading in Vapor/Fluent

Tags: vapor-fluent

I two models: Child and Parent with simple 1 to 1 relation.

The query code is code similar to this:
offset = 0
limit = 2000

```
Child.query(on: req.db)
.filter(...)
.with(\.$parent)
.range(offset..<offset + limit).all()
```

I would expect that in this case Fluent would execute a join, However inspecting the db Query I see it queries Child instances first, then makes a second request to collect parents based on the list of parent.ids.

My problem it is extremely slow. Setting limit to 2000 it takes 10 seconds to execute on a postgres database. I double checked that the db access is optimized and in fact a join query for these two related objects with the same limit 2000 takes only milliseconds so it is likely not a database.
In the code above if I remove .with statement the code runs much faster.

I setup db logging and see that the delay is happening after the second sql query to bring parents.
Does it take 10 seconds to map 2000 child/parent objects ?
Maybe I am missing something.